# Retrieve data from XML string

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to retrieve data from this XML output:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/soap/AustralianTourismWebService">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?><atdw_data_results><area area_id="9000672" area_name="Gippsland area" attribute_id_area_type="LOCAL">
<city suburb_city_postal_code="3962" attribute_id_status="ACTIVE" geocode_gda_latitude="-38.670501000" geocode_gda_longitude="146.395343000" attribute_id_geocode_proj_sys="GDA94">Agnes</city>
```

I am **able** to retrieve suburb_city_postal_code and the attribute_id_status. How do I retrieve the city name which is 'Agnes' in this case?

Please see my PHP code below:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string(trim(html_entity_decode($result)), 'SimpleXMLElement');

/** Instantiate Loop */

foreach ($result->area->city as $entry) {

$pna = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->suburb_city_postal_code, ENT_QUOTES);
$pna = str_replace("'", "''", $pna);

$str = htmlspecialchars_decode($entry->attributes()->attribute_id_status, ENT_QUOTES);
$str = str_replace("'", "''", $str);

echo  $pna. "<br />";
echo  $str . "<br />";

}
```

Thank you

Comment: `(string)$entry` in your `foreach` should work.

Comment: @Passerby: Thanks, it works. But i am not able to vote your response as the answer.

Comment: Do you want me to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending from comment:

Just use `(string)$entry` in your `foreach` should work:

```
foreach ($result->area->city as $entry) {

    /* ... */

    echo (string)$entry;
}
```